# Regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to create regex which starts with abc,then space, and then 2 digit number which should not start with 0 and which should be less than 33, then in bracket there should be minimum 3 numbers comma separated and space between them. After that if comma then regex after abc should repeat.

For ex:

1. `abc 23(340, 223, 243)`
2. `abc 3(336,455,344,880,567), 32(323,344,464)`

I've tried to do it like:

1. `/^abc(\s((?!(0))\d{1,2}[(]([1-9][0-9]*[,]){2}([1-9][0-9]*[,]*)+[)])([,]*))+/g`
2. `/^abc(\s((?!(0))\d{1,2}[(]([1-9][0-9]*[,]){2}(([1-9][0-9]*)[,]*)+[)])(([,]\s((?!(0))\d{1,2}[(]([1-9][0-9]*[,]){2}(([1-9][0-9]*)[,]*)+[)]))*))+/g`

These expression do not include case less than 33 and these expressions also allow case like:

1. `abc 23(323,345,455),`
2. `abc 23(323,345,455), 34()`

which are not required.

Comment: Things like "number less than 33" are only checkable in regex via workarounds (number 12 with 0-9 or 2 with 0-3 or 0-9). Do you have the posibility to check that in your application after this regex? A regex should ideally only check if there are numbers, not exactly numbers between a and b.

Comment: The 3 numbers need to be 3 digits?

Comment: [`^abc (?:3[1-3]|[12]\d|\d)\(\d+(?:, \d+){2,}\)(?:, (?:3[1-3]|[12]\d|\d)\(\d+(?:, \d+){2,}\))*`](https://regex101.com/r/nbrAi6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use repeating non capturing groups:

```
^abc (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3])\([1-9][0-9]*(?:, ?[1-9][0-9]*){2,}\)(?:, (?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3])\([1-9][0-9]*(?:, ?[1-9][0-9]*){2,}\))*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `abc`  Match abc and space
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3]` Match a digit 1 - 33
- `)` Close group
- `\(` Match `(`
- `[1-9][0-9]*` Match a digit 1-9 and repeat 0+ digits 0-9

  - `(?:, ?[1-9][0-9]*){2,}` Match a comma, optional space and repeat 2 or more times to match a minimum of 3 numbers
- `\)` Match `)`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,`  Match a comma and a space
  - `(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3])\([1-9][0-9]*(?:, ?[1-9][0-9]*){2,}\)` Repeat same as first pattern
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wl3bqp/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
^abc\s(?:(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3])\(\d+(?:,\s?\d+){2,}\))(?:,\s?(?:(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-3])\(\d+(?:,\s?\d+){2,}\)))*$
```

Tested against given 4 samples: https://regex101.com/r/pb8Ipv/2

If you want the matched groups for processing, replace `(?:` with `(`.

### EDIT

Fixed issue with matching single digit numbers after abc

Comment: Wouldn't this match with the single digit number after the space?

Comment: This doesn't match `abc 4(1,2,3)`

Comment: @Toto completely missed that.